# viewWillAppear not called in BCTabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

I've large project where customer want's to customize tabbar. I've choose BCTabBarController to replace UITabbarController. After few fixes it works fine but after testing I found one bug:

```
ViewWillAppear, ViewDidAppear, ViewWillDisappear ViewDidDisappear methods not called in selectded view controller and not called into BCTabBarController.
This problem appears after BCTabBarController show modal controller from instance of BCTabBarController class.
```

I've [posted issue to github repo](https://github.com/briancollins/BCTabBarController/issues/13) of briancolins, but still have no answer.

Here some code where I calling present modal view controller:

```
    - (void) presentProperlyModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([[self controllerToPresentModalFrom] respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]) // For iOS 5
    {
        [[self controllerToPresentModalFrom] presentViewController:modalViewController animated:animated completion:^(){}];
    }
    else
    {
        [[self controllerToPresentModalFrom] presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:animated];
    }
}

-(void) dismissProperlyModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)]) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:^(){}];
    }
    else
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** this issue not reproduced in iOS5 but present at iOS 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you indicated. iOS 5 forwards the messages, where previous versions do not. Here's how I handle a similar situation:

```
- (BOOL)needsMessageForwarding:(UIViewController *)vc {
    if ( [vc isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] == NO)
        return YES;

    NSString *ver = [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion;
    if ( [ver characterAtIndex:0 < '5'] )
        return YES;

    return NO;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    ...
    if ( [self needsMessageForwarding:modalViewController] )
        [modalViewController viewWillAppear:animated];
    ...
}

// repeat pattern in the other viewWill... viewDid... functions.
```

In my situation I have a list of view controllers that could be visible, so I manage which view controller is visible and forward the message to it.

Comment: I've figured out. This was a bug in BCTabBarController. There was childViewController array. If it was presented - viewwillAppear does not send.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using responds to selector instead